# How to continiously display bitmaps in OpenGL

Tags: android, opengl-es, bitmap, glsurfaceview

I've been following this guide for displaying a Bitmap in OpenGL

http://obviam.net/index.php/texture-mapping-opengl-android-displaying-images-using-opengl-and-squares/

I have, however, a queue of Bitmaps which I want to display one by one.

Should I create a new texture every time in `onDrawFrame` for a `Bitmap` I have as a head of the queue like in `onDrawFrame`:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ...

// generate one texture pointer
gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
// ...and bind it to our array
gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

// create nearest filtered texture
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

// Use Android GLUtils to specify a two-dimensional texture image from our bitmap
GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

// Clean up
bitmap.recycle();
```

Or can I somehow do only part of those operations moving some other operations on `onSurfaceChanged` probably?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to replace a texture with another texture (and you have no intention of retaining the first texture), then calling `glTexImage2D` or `GLUtils.texImage2D` is the only thing you need to do the second time through. This just replaces the existing texture data with the new data. You can call this from anywhere you have a valid OpenGL context.

If the textures are the same size, I might suggest using `glTexSubImage2D` would be an improvement, as it does not change the texture size and then can probably avoid some memory allocation on the gpu (just reuses the same backing memory).

Comment: @Tim You write _"and you have no intention of retaining the first texture"_.. How should I change the texture if I want to keep the old one two. I want to switch between the two every few seconds.